# AngularFirestoreDocument delete() does not delete documents from database

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

My function to delete a document in firestore seems not to work.

I've checked maybe the doc id it gets is incorrect but that's not the case. I tried to remove the return before the delete phrase but that didn't work either.

I also tried to add delete in the Cloud Firestore Rules but that also didn't work.

The delete function:

```
      deleteRequest(request: RequestData) {
    this.requestDoc = this.firestore.doc(`requests/${request.id}
    `);
    return this.requestDoc.delete();
  }
```

I have the same function in other component and it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in source code `delete` method returns a promise that you need to resolve it

```
/**
 * Delete a document.
 */
 delete(): Promise<void> {
    return this.ref.delete();
 }
```

so just try to chain `then` in the returns of function

`return this.requestDoc.delete().then()`

don't forget to handle the rejection.